# まさかこれから毎回ここまで来て言うのか？

Tags: translation, phrases

So I'm making a translation for a scene from a video game, and stumbled upon this phrase. I understand every word individually, but I'm struggling to make sense of all those words together. The context is as follows:

> Keisuke: 宣伝大使施策の効果は十分出ているようだ。引き続き、次回の宣伝も君達にお願いできればと思う
>
> Tsukasa: ああ！　もちろんだとも！我らワンダーランズ×ショウタイムに任せてくれ！
>
> Shosuke: ……兄貴、この報告なんだが、まさかこれから毎回ここまで来て言うのか？

I translated it as "You’re not saying that they’ll come here every time from here on out?" Which doesn't make a lot of sense in context as the ambassadors were traveling in the last part of the story.

Comment: You'd need to provide more context, but I guess the hint is that ここまで here could be translated like *(come here) all the way*, i.e., coming to  where the conversation is happening is a burden to the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Did you notice 言う at the end of the sentence lacks と/って? There is no quote in this sentence. The translation should not include "saying *that (blah-blah)*". The implied object of this 言う is the content of 報告.
- The implied subject of the sentence seems to be "we" including the speaker (Shosuke) himself.
- ～なんだが, ～ですが, ～だけど and so on can be used to bring up a topic ("speaking of ～", "regarding ～", "with respect to ～").

> ……兄貴、
> brother,...
>
> この報告なんだが、
> (regarding) this report/debriefing...
>
> まさか
> I doubt this is true but / do you really mean / don't tell me / could that mean
>
> これから毎回ここまで来て言うのか？
> will we come here and say [this] every time from now on?

So a translation is something like "Um, Keisuke/brother, do you mean...we're gonna come (all the way) here and do this debriefing every time from now on?"

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense. I knew I was missing something. Thanks!